# Display Parent / Child 1:N Relationship in Sub Grid

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created a new entity called "Contracts" which has a lookup field called "Parent Contract", which refers its parent.

When I view a contract, I want to be able to display all contracts which refer to that contract as it's parent (i.e. the children).

I have created a view called "Associated Contracts" and have filtered on **Related** Contracts (Parent Contract).

I've added a sub-grid to the form, and set the data source to:

```
Records: Only Related Records
Entity: Contracts (Parent Contract)
Default View: Associated Contracts
```

But I get no records back! I am new to CRM, what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

**Associated Contracts - Filter Criteria**
[image: Associated Contracts - Filter Criteria]

All contracts in are set to active.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of "Associated Contracts" view's filter criteria? I was able to surface the parent contract's on the sub grid. I just used the existing "All Contracts" view as the "Default View".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the part of the filter that only shows active parents, the subgrid should work as expected. Additionally, the subgrid will show related records no matter if the parent is active or inactive, which is standard behavior.

You can either edit your current `Associated Contracts` filter, or simply use one of the default views (e.g. `Active Associated Contracts`), depending on the columns you want to show.

Comment: I could have sworn I've tried this a hundred times, but removing all filters worked! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

By Default status reason for contracts is "Draft" can you add the column to the advanced find to see if they are infact "Active" or remove the filter criteria and start backtracking? I think you are mixing up state code and status code attributes.

Comment: The Contract entity in this question is a custom entity, so it would only have status Active/Inactive.